# Unable to get output for WMSGetFeatureInfo in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, getfeatureinfo

Can anyone please help me on using the WMSGetFeatureInfo in OpenLayers. I am able to add WMS Layers on top of OpenStreetMap. But while using the FeatureInfo functionality I am not getting the results. I am stuck here since long.

I am using the below code in my Application:

```
var laers = ['Network','HTNetwork','OtherObjects','LandbaseObjects']
              var  info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
                url: 'http://nv-qa:8080/gssogc/ogc?', 
                title: 'Identify features by clicking',
                queryVisible: true,
                bbox:bbb,
                i:ee.xy.x,
                j:ee.xy.y,
                info_format:'application/json',
                query_layers:laers,
                format:'image/png',
                crs:'EPSG:4326',
                layers:laers,
                width:map.getSize().w,
                height:map.getSize().h,
                eventListeners: {
                    getfeatureinfo: function(ee) {      
                                    
                        map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                            "chicken", 
                            mapb,
                            null,
                            ee.text,
                            null,
                            true
                        ));
                    
                    }
                        
                }
            });

            map.addControl(info);
           
            info.activate();
    });
```

Comment: did you turn CORS on at the server? what is the error message you see in the network log?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Does the WMS service support 'application/json' as an output format?  What actual GetFeatureInfo request is sent, and does it provided results when run in a browser?

Comment: @nmtoken Yes the WMS service supports  application/json and i am able to run it on browser without any error.Output shows the JSON format of the clicked features.

Comment: @nmtoken When i try calling the same using AJAX, i get CORS error.Access to xmlhttprequest   from origin 'http://nv-qa' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.